# JS Event based on length input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a question.
Should I bring up a div if the length of two input within a form is more than 4 characters, and hide the div when one of the two characters are less than 4.
How can I do this in javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ozgureffe/z8Ww4/2/)

```
$(function () {

    $('.input-to-check').on('keyup', function () {

        if ($('.input-to-check-1').val().length + $('.input-to-check-2').val().length > 3) {
            $('.mirror').show()
        } else {
            $('.mirror').hide()
        }

    })

})
```

Comment: Great works perfectly! Congratulations and thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you monitor all events that could change the length of the field and check its length after each one of those events and then act accordingly.  In modern browsers, you can use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) event for that.  In older browsers, it is more complicated where you need to monitor a number of events that could cause a change in the field such as `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can just use:

```
function inputChange() {
    var totLength = $('#input-1').val().length + $('#input-2').val().length;
    if (totLength >= 4) {
        $('#yourDiv').show();
    } else {
        $('#yourDiv').hide();
    }
}
$('#input-1, #input-2').change(inputChange).keyup(inputChange).keydown(inputChange);
```

That will listen to every value change, keyup and keydown event for the inputs, and check if the length of both inputs is greater than 4.

Comment: Yes, but this way I can not write anything in the first input but must enter the 4 characters in the second and then is validated, is there anything to prevent this?
Must be 4 characters in both